# finding the biggest file in a directory in linux command line

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I am currently using Linux-Ubuntu and I want to know if there is a way to do this in the command line : Suppose I have a directory and I want to find the biggest file (in size) inside this directory (eventually in its sub directories). I know I have to use `find` command with `-exec` option or with `xargs` command in addition to `sort` command but I do not know how. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right *find/exec/sort/xargs* could be usefull for this kind of use case.
One solution is this :

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%f\n'|sort -n
```

Let me explain how :

1. Extract list of file concerns  (just file with option *-type f*):

   find . -type f
2. Print the size and the name of file:

   -printf '%s\t%f\n'
3. Sort by size (with *-n* option for numeric)

   sort -n